# Should I use prefixes in CSS in these cases?

Tags: css, prefix

This is some code from some Google webpage (I found it on another question)
My question is: if the values are the same, why are prefixes needed?

```
.example {
  -webkit-border-image: url(img.png) 10px / 20px round; /* Ch <16, Saf <6 */
     -moz-border-image: url(img.png) 10px / 20px round; /* Fx <15 */
       -o-border-image: url(img.png) 10px / 20px round; /* Op (not mini) */
          border-image: url(img.png) 10px / 20px round; /* Ch 16+, Saf 6+ */
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the comments next to the lines? It means which browsers understand that line with that prefix. This could also help: http://caniuse.com/border-image One more thing: these are called **vendor prefixes**, so fire up your favorite search engine :).

Comment: Hm, but if the value is the same, why do different browsers need different prefixes and not use the prefixless variant? Seems like a waste of bytes(almost as much a waste of bytes as this question LOL).

Comment: Because for features that do not have a finalized, standard version, browser vendors can use these vendor prefixes to implement them. So let's say when Chrome 15 came out, `border-image` did not have a widely accepted standard that won't change, so they used `-webkit-border-image`. This way, if the final standard will be different from the previous version, older browsers displaying pages written with the new syntax won't break. When Chrome 16 came out, `border-image` was considered final, so it is supported in that version.

Comment: I definitely understand now! Thank you for the great answer kapa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called **vendor prefixes**.

Have you seen the comments next to the lines? It means [which browsers understand that line with that prefix](http://caniuse.com/border-image).

For features that do not have a finalized, standard version, browser vendors can use these vendor prefixes to implement them. So let's say when Chrome 15 came out, `border-image` did not have a widely accepted standard that won't change, so they used `-webkit-border-image`. This way, if the final standard will be different from the previous version, older browsers displaying pages written with the new syntax won't break. When Chrome 16 came out, `border-image` was considered final, so it is supported in that version.

Answer (score 0):

For cross Browser Support. Its there in your question itself